# Using multiple valueFields in find('list')

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-3.x

Trying to use multiple fields in my find method -

```
$users = $this->AdressesUsers->users->find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'id',
            'valueField' => ['firstname','lastname'],            
        ]);
```

Works, kinda. Because the two get seperated by a semicolon. Also tried using a mutator method, but this failed badly.

In my Function

```
'valueField' => function ($e) {
        return $e->author->get('full_name');
    }
```

In my Entity User

```
protected function _getFullName()
    {
        return $this->firstname . '  ' . $this->lastname;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would never mess with the entity, keep it without logic and as simple as possible.

A better approach here is to use what you already tried:

```
'valueField' => function ($e) {
    return $e->first_name . ' ' . $e->last_name . ' ' . $e->more;
}
```

etc
Just debug() the entity here and you will see that it contains the whole data set and you can put it together however you like.

Comment: I tried debbuging it, but there are no available fields. It is a connecting controller/table for adresses and users

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Comment: I would only consider using a virtual entity field if you happen to do this kind of "full name" concatenation in many places. `protected function _getFullName() ...` and `$e->full_name` then.

Answer (score 2):

you can use virtual field just like normal field,

```
$this->AdressesUsers->users->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => function ($e) {
           return $e->full_name;
    }
]);
```

**Additional**
you can also return array in valueField,

```
$this->AdressesUsers->users->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => function ($e) {
        $d=[];
        $d['firstname'] = $e->firstname;
        $d['lastname'] = $e->lastname;
        return $d;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use [Queries As Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects) here.
Try this:

```
$users = $this->AdressesUsers->Users->find()
              ->map(function ($row) { // map() is a collection method, it executes the query
                  $row->fullName = $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname;
                  return $row;
               })
               ->combine('id', 'fullName') // combine() is another collection method
               ->toArray(); // Also a collections library method

pr($users);  // Check your result
```